# Identify reasons for 500 errors Google auth

Tags: google-authentication, azure-api-apps

We have an api deployed on Azure that uses Google authentication. Over the weekend, the API started to throw 500 errors that were resolved after restarting the API. Is there a way to identify what the underlying cause for these errors might be?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have custom error mode in web.config file to “on” or “Remoteonly”. If 
   yes then turn it off. Add the following line to System.web element in web.config
2. Enable custom logging/instrumentation in the code which can help you in more 
   information.
   ASP.NET applications can use the System.Diagnostics.Trace class to log information to 
   the application diagnostics log. For example
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("If you're seeing this, something bad happened");
3. [Enable Detailed Error Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) - Detailed version of the html files produced when 
   your website responds with an error message. This is good to enable for debugging 
   some error responses in your website. It is stored in the website's file system.
4. [Web Server Logging](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.XGqaLOgzY2w) - Also known as HTTP logs or IIS logs, this will log all requests 
   to your website in W3C Extended Log File Format.
5. [Failed Request Tracing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/) - Also known as FREB, here you can get lots of information 
   from IIS through its different stacks for each failing request.